# Macbook Pro 2015: Key cap will not snap back into place

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Following the instructions in this video
[How To Fix MacBook Pro Keyboard Keys Tutorial | Replace Mac Keyboard](https://youtu.be/Epo0lbhmc4s),
I very carefully removed the key cap without touching the scissoring mechanism.

When trying to snap the key cap back in place, I discovered that I am unable to do so.

When searching for a solution to my problem, I discovered that others have had the problem as well but I was not able to find a solution.

Given the variety of configurations I have seen, I am including close up images.

[image: key cap backside]

[image: keyboard]

Answer (score 2):

I have shown others in person how to do this. I've found it helps to first recognize exactly how it attaches, to understand how the pieces can fit together and will later move correctly during use.

The top and bottom of that key cap are attached to the scissor mechanism in two different ways. To reinstall it, you must slide the key almost parallel to the keyboard surface to hook the two "shelf" hooks (top of your pictures) successfully first, then press the "grabber" claws (bottom of your pictures) straight toward the keyboard to pop into place around the cylinders they hold.

If the bottom grabbers have attached first, they must be re-removed since they hold the scissor and cap shelves exactly aligned with each other. Forcing the aligned shelves past each other will just bend and damage the plastic.

Because the key "well" is such a tight fit on some of Apple's keyboards, the key cannot slide its shelves onto the scissor's shelves with the scissor mechanism in the lowered position pictured. You may be able to coax it up, but you can't see what's happening under the key cap. If you're not confident the shelves are hooked, don't push and risk ruining it. I usually slide something very thin under the an axle on one side of the scissor to hold it up. That makes it much easier to confidently slide the shelves together with no pressure. Then just press the bottom of the key down straight toward the keyboard and the grabbers will pop into place.